# My VOSS oven makes a clicking noise when cooling down

Tags: oven, noise

Our 10 years old VOSS electric oven model IEL 671-OT (conventional + convection) makes a loud and fast clicking sound when cooling down. It starts usually around 5 minutes after being switched off and will last until it is completely cool.

You can stop the sound for a period by simply turning the oven on and off again. After a few minutes it will start again though. Then you can stop it again by turning it on an off and so forth, until it eventually stops.

When the noise is sounding, the light in the clock display is considerably weaker than normal, around 50%. It regains the normal brightness immediately if you turn on the oven (which stops the noise) but will again go low when the noise starts.

I guess the sound comes from a relay, but I have no idea what the relay does and why it clicks.

I often fix stuff myself and don't mind disassembling the oven, but I would like to get a few ideas first, if possible.

UPDATE:
Here is a short [video](https://goo.gl/photos/mPEc4PNPnGfz9MeE9) where you can both see and hear the problem. Note how the dimming of the display is related to the clicking noise. In thise case the oven only reluctantly turned on when I pressed the switch, this is quite unusual. Normally it starts without problems and then the noise disappears.

Comment: VOSS is the brand, right? What model is it, or what type of oven is it (convection, conventional, microwave)?

Comment: Sorry, should of course have given these details. I have updated my question.

Comment: Are you sure that the display darkens when the clicking starts (and not just when you power it off)? What happens if it's clicking and you throw the associated circuit breaker?

Comment: Yes, the dimming of the display is clearly related to the sound. I have updated my question with a video showing both the dimming and the sound. If I cut the power, the sounds stops immediately and returns after a few seconds when the power comes back.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like something's wrong with your oven's controller board. Assuming you speak Danish, you can search for Voss parts [here](http://reservedele.electrolux.dk/category/Voss); I believe your specific model's parts will be [here](http://reservedele.electrolux.dk/search?ssv=IEL%20671-OT). (Note, though, that I don't see a controller board available, although my nonexistent Danish might be misleading me.)

Comment: I am Danish! You are right, there are no controller board in the parts list. However, I don't think the controller necessarily needs replacing. The problem has been there for a year a so, but in a mild degree. Ie. it took just a short time for the noise to stop. Recently it has been worsening a lot though. So it might be fixable. I will wait some more time to see if something comes up here, then I will just dig into the oven.